# Print pdf document from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I need to print a pdf document that I have altered without saving it back as a new pdf document.  This code below works without a problem.  However I would like to do this quite differently and I´m simultaneously having a brain-lag and can´t see the solution.

**My code example**

```
byte[] result;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("c:\\templatePdf.pdf");
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms);

    /* abbreviated but here I alter the template pdf */

    pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
    pdfStamper.Close();
    result = ms.GetBuffer();
}

/* Instead of saving a new file I would rather like to print
   the altered template pdf in memory and then discard it */
using (FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\\Test.pdf"))
{
    fs.Write(result, 0, (int)result.Length);
}

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Test.pdf";
process.StartInfo.Verb = "printto";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + ppr_PrinterDropDown.Text + "\"";
process.Start();
File.Delete("C:\\Test.pdf");
```

Comment: You should use `result = ms.GetBuffer()` - you should use `ToArray()`. Otherwise you'll have a bunch of trailing nulls. Also, use `File.WriteBytes` or just `MemoryStream.WriteTo` to make life simpler.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @JonSkeet but how would I deal with it within the process whereas process needs the filename to read from? (I mean so I can print the pdf)  ;)

Comment: It wasn't meant to be an answer - it was just an aside around the existing code. I suspect you'll still need to use a file, as per Marc's answer.

Comment: Yes you´re both probably right about that.  Thank you for your comments  :)

Comment: I've been researching something similar (update a pdf form then print, without saving intermediate to disk). Did you ever figure a way to print without disk writes? It seems like the answers lead away from that as an option, but figured I'd ask.

Comment: I never got to that.  I ended up saving it to a temp location and then returning the file to the browser for download or view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a file-based API, then you will struggle to do it without a file. You *might* be able to setup a named pipe server, but frankly that is a huge fiddle. I would, however, be tempted to look around for a fully managed PDF library with print support. But ultimately... what harm is the file system doing, *really*? Probably not a lot. I *might* suggest a few tweaks, though:

1. use the temp area (`Path.GetTempPath()`), not `C:\Test`
2. wait for the process to finish before deleting the file

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MarcGravell. That´s probably the only way then, at least I can´t find any solution with the way I´m handling this at the moment.  I might look for some pdf library to help me with a solution but I think I´ll take the easy way out and just use the temp location :)

Answer (score 0):

First We Need To Write into our Memory Stream and then with the help of Memory Stream method "WriteTo" we can write to the Response of the Page as shown in the below code.

```
   MemoryStream filecontent = null;
   filecontent =//CommonUtility.ExportToPdf(inputXMLtoXSLT);(This will be your MemeoryStream Content)
   Response.ContentType = "image/pdf";
   string headerValue = string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", formName.ToUpper() + ".pdf");
   Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", headerValue);

   filecontent.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);

   Response.End();
```

FormName is the fileName given,This code will make the generated PDF file downloadable by invoking a PopUp.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Response of the page'?  What method is 'Response' coming from?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. The hard part is getting useful info about print status completion and total page numbers.

```
var pq = LocalPrintServer.GetDefaultPrintQueue();
var theJob = pq.AddJob();
try{
    using(var js = theJob.JobStream){
        var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes("yourPathToPdf");
        js.Write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
    }
    var done=false;
    while(!done)
    {
        pq.Refresh();
        theJob.Refresh();
        done = theJob.IsCompleted || theJob.IsDeleted || theJob.IsPrinted;
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    //handle this
}
finally{
    theJob?.Dispose();
    pq?.Dispose();
}
```

This is assuming your printer has native PDF support, of course. Otherwise you will have to do the rendering work yourself on the client and send it not as a raw stream.

Comment: Thank you for that comment even though this thread is actually quite old  :)  I might give this a try when I get the change and give you feedback.